# How to upload local json file and save content into a variable Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I want to upload a JSON file and save it's content into a variable.
I wrote the following code:

`<input type="file" id="file" ref="fileSelect" class="custom-file-input" @change="previewFiles" />`

```
previewFiles() { 
    let files = this.$refs.fileSelect.files
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onReaderLoad;
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);  

    function onReaderLoad(event){
        //console.log(event.target.result);
        let json = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
        this.t = json       
    }
}
```

Basically, I am working with vue, so I want to store the local JSON file into the variable **t** so that I can use it in other places. Currently nothing is getting stored in **t**.
I tried various other solutions but nothing is working.
My end goal is to display this json's content as a table on another page and also use its content in other functions as well.
I am new to javascript so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, let's get out of the way that `event.target.result` is the JSON text, and what you call `json` is an *Object* / *Array*. Anyway, the problem here is that when you do `this.t = json`, the `this` refers to the onReaderLoad function, not your Vue context. Use an arrow function instead: `reader.onload = ({ target: { result }}) => { this.t = JSON.parse(result); }`

Comment: Ohh ok.  Thanks, arrow function works.

Comment: @ChrisG hey this works fine with ```<script>```   , but when I use ```<script lang='ts'>``` I get the error ```Object is of type 'unknown'``` in the line ```let files = this.$refs.fileSelect.files``` . Do you know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't before [googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=ts+error+object+is+of+type+%27unknown%27) ;)

Comment: Yeah, I also searched it, but none of the fixes were working for me, but I created a new issue.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: With TypeScript you should always state the type of variables. That's the whole idea behind Typescript. And please do not post a new question here as soon as you encounter any random issue; try to fix the problem yourself first, especially as long as you are a beginner. The chances that nobody else has had these problems before you are zero.